# What does the /gamerule speed command do?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I was messing around with the gamerule command and found a gamerule I didn't know, so I tried it and found no noticeable changes. I tried looking up what it was but came up with no results. Does anyone know what it does? BTW I am playing Minecraft 1.10.2.

Screenshot:
[image: Gamerule Speed]

Answer (score 1):

It is a custom gamerule. When using the `/gamerule` command to modify the name of a gamerule that isn't default, a custom inert gamerule is created instead. "speed" is not a default gamerule.

Custom gamerules do nothing on their own, requiring the use of command mechanisms to detect the value and manually do something with it. If you do not have any command mechanisms that use it, then it does nothing at all.

Comment: Oh It was probably the One Command Mod I had Installed in my world. Thanks.